# Angular Observables Chainging calls and setting child object data

Tags: angular

I've just started looking at the latest version of angular cli. I have created two services, one is for addresses, the other for persons. When creating a person, I want to hit the create method on the address service before creating the person to give me an id of the newly created address, then set that to the person object and then post that.

```
   return create(model:Person) : Observable<Person> {
        this.addressService.create(model.Address)
        .subscribe((result:Address) =>{
            model.AddressId = result.Id;
            return this.http.post(url,model,httpOptions);
        });
    }
```

obviously this is not right, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `mergeMap` to chain the observables.

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

create(model: Person): Observable < Person > {
    return this.addressService.create(model.Address)
        .pipe( 
           mergeMap((result: Address) => {
             model.AddressId = result.Id;
             return this.http.post(url, model, httpOptions); 
          })
        )
}
```

Comment: mergeMap is the correct name for flatMap these days

Comment: Hi thanks for the updates, ok this code is telling me Observale <Object >is not assignable to Observable <Person>, do i need to specify a type on the second post?

Comment: add a type for post req `return this.http.post<Person> (url, model, httpOptions);`

Comment: You can also use switchMap.